# How can I write API's to chat with friends in google hangout?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I am looking for a way to send chat messages to a google hangout session from a different client. let's say one party is using skype and other google hangout. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about a Hangout Text Chat or if you mean a Hangout Video Call?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much anything you can do in an iframe, you can do in a [Google+ Hangout app](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/). So, if you wanted to implement chat, you would:

- Create a chat client that can run in a web browser (a HTML5 chat client, for example)
- Integrate the client into the hangout through [embedding the HTML markup into Gadget XML](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/writing)
- Authorize the user to your chat client after the hangout begins using some unique identifier that can connect that user to another client

That's a little generalized but the details for things like where to display the chat and how to restrict it to the right people who are chatting is really going to be up to you.